# mySQL Script Error

Tags: mysql, authentication, debian, openvpn

I've been trying to get an OpenVPN server running Debian-7-Wheezy to authenticate via mySQL all day. I have mySQL hosted on another server running WHM and cPanel. I added the OpenVPN server's IP to the whitelist for database connections, checked all my credentials and double checked the config file. When I run: `/etc/openvpn/script/test_connect_db.sh test 1234` I recieve this error:

```
/etc/openvpn/script/test_connect_db.sh: line 6: mysql: command not found
```

authentication failed.

The file located at: `/etc/openvpn/script/test_connect_db.sh` looks exactly like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/openvpn/script/config.sh

##Test Authentication

username=$1

password=$2

user_id=$(mysql -h$HOST -P$PORT -u$USER -p$PASS $DB -sN -e "select user_id from user where       user_id = '$username' AND user_pass = '$password' AND user_enable=1 AND user_start_date !=    user_end_date AND TO_DAYS(now()) >= TO_DAYS(user_start_date) AND (TO_DAYS(now()) <=    TO_DAYS(user_end_date) OR user_end_date='0000-00-00')")

##Check user
[ "$user_id" != '' ] && [ "$user_id" = "$username" ] && echo "user : $username" && echo  'authentication ok.' && exit 0 || echo 'authentication failed.'; exit 1
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't event getting far enough to attempt a mysql connection to begin with.

The error you specified indicated it can't even find the mysql client.

Can you successfully just run "mysql" from the command line outside the script?

If so that would indicate your $PATH variable isn't set properly in scope of the script.

You didn't say what config.sh is doing.  Maybe that's over writing the PATH variable?

Either way if you can run mysql from the command line then run

```
which mysql
```

That should give you the fully qualified path to the client binary and you could use that in your script.